# Python3 idiomatic way to dispatch method call on abstract base classes

Tags: python

I'm using `Python 3.10.5`.

I've got the following class which is designed to:

- receive an object
- lookup which class should handle the request
- invoke a method on that class that has been looked up

What I have so far:

```py
class BaseHandler(ABC):
    def handle(self):
        pass


class HandlerOne(BaseHandler):
    def handle(self):
        # some stuff


class HandlerTwo(BaseHandler):
    def handle(self):
        # some other stuff


class CommandOne():
    def __init__(self):
        # some attributes


class CommandTwo():
    def __init__(self):
        # some attributes


class CommandDispatcher():
    def __init__(self):
        self._commands = {
            CommandOne.__name__: HandlerOne,
            CommandTow.__name__: HandlerTwo,
        }

    @property
    def get_handler(self, command: object): 
        return self._commands.get(type(command).__name__)

    @classmethod
    def dispatch(self, command: object)
        handler = self.get_handler(command)
        handler.handle() # <-- this doesn't work because the interpreter doesn't know that each handler is of type `BaseHandler`

//
```

I'm new to python, but have experience with Java and C#.  I've been looking at this for a while but think I've been so used to working with statically typed languages that I'm approaching this incorrectly.

What is the idiomatic way to design this with Python so that from the clients perspective I can achieve the following:

```py
dispatcher = CommandDispatcher()
command_one = CommandOne()
command_two = CommandTwo()

dispatcher.dispatch(command_one)
dispatcher.dispatch(command_two)
```

Comment: _"this doesn't work because the interpreter doesn't know that each handler is of type `BaseHandler`"_ why do you think that's the case?

Comment: Because there was no autocomplete on my IDE (VS Code) :S. I'm quickly validating that now though...

Comment: Also, you're trying to call an instance method `handle`, but never instantiate any class (i.e: `CommandOne.__name__: HandlerOne`)

Comment: In my opinion, I would probably convert the commands to a dataclass object. They seem like they just keep some initial properties.
I would convert the handle function to be the `def __call__(self):` and then `handler.handle()` should be `handler()`

Comment: I tried using your code, but it's got a few issues with it. Please fix it and tell us exactly what's the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your code to work by registering the handlers as callable classes in the dict.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

class HandlerOne:
    def __call__(self):
        print("Handler one")

class HandlerTwo:
    def __call__(self):
        print("Handler two")

@dataclass
class CommandOne:
    pass

@dataclass
class CommandTwo:
    pass

class CommandDispatcher():
    def __init__(self):
        self._commands = {
            CommandOne.__name__: HandlerOne(),
            CommandTwo.__name__: HandlerTwo(),
        }

    def __get_handler(self, command: object):
        return self._commands.get(type(command).__name__)

    def dispatch(self, command: object):
        handler = self.__get_handler(command)
        handler()


dispatcher = CommandDispatcher()
dispatcher.dispatch(CommandOne())
```